# Internet Explorer image rendering 1 pixel off

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The website I'm working on ([schmuckzauberwelt.ch](http://www.schmuckzauberwelt.ch)) has a fancy frame around it which adjusts somewhat dynamically to the available viewport. In order to keep the main site usable, the frame is not one image, but rather cut into four pieces (top, right, bottom, left) which are positioned around the main site. The gist of the html code is this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<img id="mirror-top" src="mirror-long.png" alt="" name="mirror-top" /> 
<img id="mirror-bottom" src="mirror-long.png" alt="" name="mirror-bottom" />
<img id="mirror-left" src="mirror-short.png" alt="" name="mirror-left" /> 
<img id="mirror-right" src="mirror-short.png" alt="" name="mirror-right" />
<div id="mainsite">
[...]
</div> <!-- end of mainsite -->
</div> <!-- end of wrapper -->
```

These four .png's are completely transparent; they get a z-index of 1 in order to put them over the main site:

```
#mirror-top,
#mirror-bottom,
#mirror-left,
#mirror-right {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Then a bunch of media queries give them the right size / position and load in the the actual frame image as a background (one example here):

```
@media (min-height: 600px) and (max-height: 647px) and (min-width: 1000px),
(min-width: 1000px) and (max-width: 1079px) and (min-height: 600px) 
{
[...] 
#mirror-top,
#mirror-bottom {
width: 1000px;
height: 100px;
background-image: url(mirror-long-600px.jpg);   
}
#mirror-bottom {
top: 500px;
}
#mirror-left,
#mirror-right {
width: 100px;
height: 400px;
top: 100px;
background-image: url(mirror-short-600px.jpg);
}
#mirror-right {
    left: 900px;
}
}
```

And finally, in order to save on bandwidth, the top and the bottom as well as the left and the right frame piece are the actually same image, they just get flipped via css before being loaded in:

```
#mirror-bottom,
#mirror-right {
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
-o-transform: rotate(180deg);
transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Now, all of this works fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Mobile Safari from display sizes of smartphones all the way up to a 27inch iMac

BUT

you guessed it: Internet Explorer has a problem with it: The bottom and the right mirror somehow are one pixel off, blurring the background image and creating ugly lines...

See for yourself: [imgur.com album](http://imgur.com/a/n36Rh) (First image windows 7 IE11, second Windows 8.1 IE11)

Apart from that, I noticed that everything is fine when making the window so small, that the smallest media query kicks in and positions the site top left with scrollbars rather than centering it horizontally and vertically.
The general code for that is the following:

```
#wrapper {
z-index: 0;
background-color: white;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
}
```

In all but the smallest media query, there's something like this:

```
#wrapper {
width: 1000px;
height: 600px;
margin-top: -300px;
margin-left: -500px;
}
```

And in the smallest one, this:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 830px;
    height: 498px;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
}
```

So, the question is: what can I do? Or at least, where could I start debugging? Right now I'm completely lost...

I know that the code a little bit complicated and I tried my best to sum it up but most of the relevant code is scattered around several media queries, so maybe you need to take a quick look at it with firebug...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a typical "whitepace between inline-block elements" problem.

What I would try first is to remove the carriage returns in your HTML code, like this :

```
<div id="wrapper"><!--
--><img id="mirror-top" src="mirror-long.png" alt="" name="mirror-top" /><!--
--><img id="mirror-bottom" src="mirror-long.png" alt="" name="mirror-bottom" /><!--
--><img id="mirror-left" src="mirror-short.png" alt="" name="mirror-left" /><!--
--><img id="mirror-right" src="mirror-short.png" alt="" name="mirror-right" /><!--
--><div id="mainsite">
[...]
</div> <!-- end of mainsite -->
</div> <!-- end of wrapper -->
```

It actually puts the carriage returns (causing the whitespace problems) in comment, so it's basically as you putting all the `img` tags next to each other, but with this notation you can keep your code indented.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but it doesn't seem to do it. Maybe because display is set to block rather than inline-block...

Answer (score 0):

If the issue *is* whitespace related, you can also try explicitly setting the `line-height` or `font-size` to 0 on all relevant elements/DIVs/wrappers - and then re-establish the line-height/font-size on your central content area.

If the problem persists, another way of presenting the HTML layout which may solve your issue would be to break your content into further DIVs - very roughly - like this;

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="top"><img id="mirror-top" /></div>
    <div id="middle">
        <div id="left"><img id="mirror-left" /></div>
        <div id="center">Lorem ipsum ...</div>
        <div id="right"><img id="mirror-right" /></div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom"><img id="mirror-bottom" /></div>    
</div>
```

In this example, you would apply your dynamic sizing to the divs (possibly with percentages) - not the images - and set the images to `width: 100%;`.  You shouldn't need to set the height of the images at all.

`div#left` and `div#right` could be floated, with `div#center` kept independent using margins/negative-margins.

Make sure that the `#top`, `#left`, `#right` and `#bottom` divs have `font-size: 0;` - because they contain no text; this will resolve any whitespace issues that the images might have.

Also, make sure that your wrapping DIVs have a `background-color` to match the gray.  This isn't a magic bullet, but it should hide the outer-most 1px lines making the issue far less prominent.

Comment: Thank you for your response; I did try the div's you suggested but that wasn't it either. It's also not a whitespace issue, but the horizontal and vertical centering was the problem. The solution: centering the website vertically and horizontally using margin: auto; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 1; right: 0 rather than a negative margin of half the width and height of the content. It only works when browsing in a maximised window though... if you drag around the border of the window, the lines still occur. Seems to be defenitely an IE issue... works fine in every other browser.